# How to retrieve DATE value from SQL Server to TEXTBOX for data UPDATE

Tags: asp.net, datetime, gridview, sql-update

i am using this code for retrieving value from sql column to textbox. and i am using textmode="date" at input time to save DATE in database.And using a gridview link i want to redirect the row data to another page for edit and update.But the DATE value is not coming to TEXTBOX.

```
Date_of_st.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
```

Also tried these snippets:

```
 1 Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Employee_DOB"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
 2 ((DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Coat_CUSTM_Date"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
 3 suDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(conv, "MM-dd-yyyy", null);
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Not getting the DATE Value after using this code , in textbox

Comment: Could you please try with removing `textmode="date"`?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the row and col are correct, try this:

```
  var date = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
  var dateRif = new DateTime();
  if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out dateRif))
  {
      //Do what you want
  }
```